# “I’m happy to help”

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

Let’s say I just helped someone and they thanked me for it, would it be contextually appropriate to reply to their “thank you” with “i’m Happy to help” 
I’m asking if I can use the expression after helping someone as a way to say “i’m Glad I was able to help” or “It didn’t bother me at all to help” ?

Or should I only use “i’m Happy to help” when I want to offer someone help ?

Comment: “I’m glad I was able to help” works well. The one about being bothered is very poor. But unless you have more to add, do you need to reply at all?

Answer (score 2):

These are all acceptable:

> You're welcome.
>
> No problem. [(Note: there exists some debate that this is primarily used by younger generations only, and may cause offense when spoken to older generations.)](https://allthingslinguistic.com/post/124189121619/no-problem-vs-youre-welcome)
>
> It wasn't a problem./It wasn't an issue./It wasn't a bother. (used only when the person thanking you is apologizing for the effort/sacrifice/etc. that went into helping them)
>
> I'm happy to help./I was happy to help.
>
> I'm glad I was able to help.

If you're going to offer to help, you could say

> I'll be happy to help!

This isn't a full list or anything, but hopefully the additional options help provide you some context as to what's acceptable and what may not be acceptable.

Comment: And there are a great many more things you can say, including "It was nothing", "Don't mention it", "It was my pleasure".

Comment: @jonathanjo True! I edited my question to note that I did not provide an exhaustive list.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to be absolutely correct, you need to take into account the relationship between the thanker and the person being thanked.

So, the problem some of us see with "no problem" is that it is used sometimes by people for whom the task they have done was never supposed to be a problem in the first place, such as the barman who brings you the drink you have ordered.

If you read the wonderful works of PG Wodehouse, you will find that the servant Jeeves's response to being thanked is along the lines  "Not at all" or "I endeavour to give satisfaction". Jeeves would never have uttered the words "no problem".

Now, if you were to ask some person whom you regard as very important and in some sense your superior to do something, and they do it, their response to your thanks, could not possibly be "I endeavour to give satisfaction" but could be "it was no trouble" - words that are almost the same as "no problem".